# Finding missing SD using paired-test

Tags: standard-deviation, missing-data, paired-data

I have a problem finding **missing SD from a study**

***Please refer to the image below***

[image]

Note:
What is provided?

- Each timepoint's mean
- p-value for paired-test between (post) and (pre) score

What is NOT provided?

- t-value
- 95% CI
- Standard Error

Is there anywhere I could find the SD for each timepoint?

Thanks in advance :D